# SwiftUI: How to toggle an alert presenter from a change in ViewModel

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm, swiftui

I have a simple game in SwiftUI. This is the view (with just the important parts for clarity).

```
struct MainScreen: View {
    @ObservedObject var game = GameEngine()

    @State var gameOver = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                Color.backgroundGray.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)

                // MARK: - Screen Content
                VStack {
                }
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $showLeader) { LeaderBoard(game: game) }
            .alert(isPresented: $gameOver) {
                Alert(title: Text("Game Over"),
                      message: Text("There are no more moves available."),
                      dismissButton: .default(Text("OK"), action: {
                        self.game.resetGame(boardSize: boardSize)
                        if game.state == .won {
                            self.showLeader.toggle()
                        }
                      }))
            }
```

The GameEngine() class has this published state which is an enum. I want to change the MainScreen @State property whenever the GameEngine State property is .won or .over, but I cannot figure how to properly observe that. That property changes in the model, whenever the game situation changes, so it shouldn't be changed in the view.

```
enum State {
    case start
    case won
    case running
    case over
}

@Published var state: State = .running {
    didSet {
        switch state {
        case .over:
            print("game over")
        case .won:
            let record = Record(playerName: playerName, score: score)
            leaderBoard.append(record)
            defaults.set(highest, forKey: "High Score")
        case .start:
            print("started")
        case .running:
            print("running")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `onReceive`:

```
NavigationView {
    ...
}
.onReceive(game.$state) { state in 
    if [.won, .over].contains(state) {
        self.gameOver = true
    }
}
```